# inner join two SELECT statements in ONE query AND show results from BOTH tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I want the use 2 SELECT statements and an INNER JOIN from different queries BUT also want to show the two different results, from different tables in the same query. Like this..

```
  SELECT column1 FROM earth e1 that is null
                     +
  SELECT chair5 FROM space s1 that is not null

  INNER JOIN space s1 ON e1.car = s1.truck

  ORDER BY e1.column,s1.chair5
```

How do I show the results of two different queries while using an INNER JOIN?

Comment: Are you saying you want the result of the select statements printed as well as the results of the subsequent inner join printed?

Comment: Yes, I need them both printed and both tables inner joined by a similar column

Comment: Please provide sample data for both tables, and an example of the expected result.  Otherwise, it's not very clear.

Comment: Your example is not legal SQL, so it's hard to tell *exactly* what you're after.  Could you include a simple example of data that would be in the two tables and what you want the output to look like?

Comment: I think that you need to make these separate queries. You're basically saying you want the results before and after. Earth and Space are only joined by a single attribute, and tuples that don't match will be filtered out. The FROM statement operates on a single relation, and I don't see how you can access the relation prior to the join as well as the resulting relation after the join in one statement.

Comment: Also, do you want a new relation with the before and after or do you just want to print out the before and after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume the table `T1` contains values `'A','B','C'` and table `T2` contains values `'A','B','D'`

You may query

```
select 'T1' as source, col from t1
union all
select 'T2' as source, col from t2
union all
select 'join T1,T2' as source, t1.col from t1 inner join t2
on t1.col= t2.col
order by 1,2
;
```

getting

```
SOURCE     COL  
---------- -----
T1         A    
T1         B    
T1         C     
T2         A      
T2         B    
T2         D   
join T1,T2 A   
join T1,T2 B
```

The first column identifies the source: single query or a join

Alternatively, which I'll prefer you may get the same information (more compressed) using FULL OUTER JOIN

```
with fj as (
select t1.col t1_col, t2.col t2_col 
from t1 full outer join t2
on t1.col= t2.col
)
select 
case when t1_col is not null and t2_col is not null then 'both'
when  t1_col is not null   then 'T1 only'
when  t2_col is not null then 'T2 only' end as source,
nvl(t1_col, t2_col) col
from fj
order by 1,2
```

.

```
SOURCE  COL  
------- ----------
T1 only C        
T2 only D       
both    A      
both    B
```

Comment: But in OPs example we don't know that column1 and chair5 are the same attribute type so how can one union those tuples?

Comment: Ill try to provide better data examples. Sorry

Comment: @TrickyDBA simple update your question if the answer doesn't match